# SSIS 2012 pass values from child package to parent with project deployment model

Tags: ssis

i'm using the new project deployment model.

I have a master package called ETL.  The first thing my ETL package does is run a package called get SFTP files as shown.

[image]

Within Get SFTP files a foreach loop gets the ClientID.  HOW do i pass this value back to the parent package ETL??? To do inserts etc.

[image]

Comment: If it's a foreach loop, is it only sending back a single value or are you expecting to get a stream of ids back?

Comment: Hi billin, thanks for your response. I would be expecting a single value.  For example i would want to execute a data flow for each client/company in a client/company table.

Comment: billin, could you please provide a brief/simple example of how i would output a variable in a child package to overwrite a value in parent package?  thanks.

Comment: From what I was able to discover, Parameter, the new way of passing data from one package to another is a one-way street in 2012. I haven't tried either "classic" approach for parent child parameters (explicit configuration or variable encapsulation) but they may still work

Comment: sorry i'm fairly new to this i'm basically learning with ssis 2012... and was getting the impression that passing variables from parent to child is easy i.e. parameter binding on execute sql task but not sure how to do it the other way round... child --> parent...

Comment: Maybe scripting helps you, look at "Accessing Parent Package Variables" in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137609.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have spoken with a couple experts about this there is no NATIVE way of doing this in SSIS.  I did see a mention about a way of doing this which is effectively a hack in a script task, but anyone reading this store results from your variables into a table and reference from there.  Parameter binding on the execute package task is currently a ONE way street Parent --> Child.

Comment: What a shame :( ... But your post is old already. Does anyone know if there's any news on this?

Answer (score 12):

Here is a way to pass a value from a child package variable to a parent package variable.

**Script Task:** (in child package)

```
// Populate collection of variables.
// This will include parent package variables.
Variables vars = null;
Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref vars);

// Lock the to and from variables. 
Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::MyParentPackageVar");
Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::MyChildPackageVar");

// Apparently need to call GetVariables again after locking them.
// Not sure why - perhaps to get a clean post-lock set of values.
Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref vars);
vars["User::MyParentPackageVar"].Value = vars["User::MyChildPackageVar"].Value;

vars.Unlock();
```

This code was actually from a pre-2012 SSIS Package that I just finished upgrading to SSIS for SQL Server 2012 (in Visual Studio 2012), and converted to project deployment model.

Initially, the execution died (after a lengthy delay) on the variable assignment line.  But then I added the "User::" prefix, which apparently was necessary for at least one, but not all of the variables I was assigning this way.  The prefix was *not* necessary in SSIS for SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Very good Solution with the explanation. You scripted it very well.

Comment: The first `Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref vars);` is not required.  It does not have to be written twice.

Comment: @Zach Blocker. Is this solution works with 2015 version as well?

Comment: I don't know - still using 2012 to maintain our packages. Post back what you find out.

Answer (score 4):

The Simple Solution is

Add The Variables in Master Package (which Needs Back to use in Master)

Assign Values in Child Packages to Master Package Variables (Access no issue in child for Master Package Varibales)

And Once Control came back to Master Used them ...and because they are declared in Master Package you can use their values which were assinged under Child Packages

Comment: Thanks you, this answer helped me. However, it was not easy to comprehend in the first read. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I am still working on migrating SSIS packages from previous versions into SSIS 2012, so the information given here may not work with 2012 version.

In previous versions, we found out that the child package has visibility (and can change) SSIS Variables values in the Parent Package that are in the scope (usually the Parent Package's Global Variables) of the Child package at run time.

This is done by developing the child package as a stand alone package using the same name of the Parent Package variables that the child package needs to change at run time.

When the Child Package is fully developed and tested as stand alone and before deploying it, the variables with the same name of the Parent Package's variables should be deleted from the Child Package and set the Delay Validation property of the Child Package to true to avoid validation errors at deployment time.

At Run Time, when the Parent Package calls (or runs) the Child Package, in fact the Child Package becomes a component of the Parent Package and therefore can reference and change variables in the Parent Package within the scope of the Child Package.

Hope this does not sound very confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to include your child and parent packages in the same project and use project variables to pass to the child package. You can call or change the value in the child package and the value would be available in the parent package as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just found [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6089/pass-ssis-variable-from-parent-to-child-package-in-sql-server-integration-services/) on the web.

Basically, you need to specify the parent package variable (by typing it in) in the ReadOnlyVariables or ReadWriteVariables section of the Script Task Editor (see image below courtesy of MSSQLTips.com).

[image: mssqltips.com Script Task Setup]

After that, in the Script Task code, just assign or read the values. I don't know if it will work if you specify the "User::" prefix.

```cs
Dts.Variables["gettingvalue"].Value = Dts.Variables["Passingvalue"].Value
```

*EDIT: There's a bit more to it than this. Just give the MSSQLTips article a read.*