# SSIS: Execute Process Task return value

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS Package "Parent" that calls another package called "child". I can send parameters from Parent to Child, but i need to send a value on Child user variables to the parent. I know there's no native way of doing this, but how can i do that?

Comment: there is a good discussion in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288766/ssis-2012-pass-values-from-child-package-to-parent-with-project-deployment-model/20434973#20434973

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a user variable and update it during your package "child" execution.
Then you can use this value where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Look's like you can access a "parent" variable in Script Task. You just need to remove the User:: prefix from the variable name, and it will look on the "global" scope.

This way, its possible to "return" values to the parent package