# SSIS - modular "child" packages -- variable scope and passing variables to package

Tags: variables, ssis, scope

I'm trying to think ahead with some of this SSIS project/ package design, being familiar with ETL in Pentaho Data Integration.

I'm rolling some custom logging (to be re-used).

Another common "component" across ETL scripts is the old "find the data range to pull".

I suppose some people just say "take X months back from today and work that in" -- that's quick to roll but possibly somewhat lazy. I prefer some common incremental patterns like "query last entered date, pull from there."

ANYWAY, so in these ETL scripts I'm creating modular "child packages" to be re-used. Whether they're logging, date range finders, calculation scripts, etc. To eventually be used across 20-30 packages.

I'm just wondering --- these child packages -- if I'm re-using the "date range finder" and passing it to variables "start_range" and "end_range" in the child package, that packages -- possible called multiple times by various parents -- it can pass it's unique results to each parent that called it, right? Hope that makes sense -- I suppose I can test it out here. I'm concerned if eventually two parents call it at the same time -- I would think two separate/ independepent executions happen but who knows.

Answer (score 1):

"Parent-Child" scheme is possible and quite used in SSIS.

- Parent, one or several, can call the same child package in its own execution process. Since it is done in parent execution process or spawned from it, Child executions are independent when calling the same package. The parent package can pass parameters to the child.
- Child package cannot return any value except Error state and Error description, which can be handled at Parent side. There is an [unofficial way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209753/ssis-2012-pass-variable-from-child-to-parent-package) to set Parent package variable from the Child.
- Parent package can execute the Child either it its own process (called *in-process exec*) or in separate process (called *out-of-process exec*).

I use this Parent-Child package scheme for complex ETL/ELT tasks. Child packages do the ETL; Parent - orchestrate and run Child packages, but do not perform ETL tasks itself.

In SSIS 2016+ you can use so called SSIS Package Parts, which are code fragments plugged into the Main package. Again, there is a hack way to change variables of the main package from the Package Part - create a variable in the Part with the same name as in the Main package, and then - manually set variable scope to the Main package. See [more use cases](https://prathy.com/2016/06/my-thoughts-on-ssis-2016-ssis-package-parts-2/) of Package Parts.

Comment: Hmm I'll have to experiment with the in-process/ out-of-process distinction. Hmm not too happy about the fact that Child Packages can not "set" or "modify" a variable in a Parent package. Is that right? Like for instance --- the "date range" modular child package. It takes in parameters (like table, date_column, range_logic) -- and then returns the 'start and end' range of the ETL query to be passed to the parent. This isn't natively possible? --- And the reason it's a child package vs. a simple execute SQL script? .... So if I have to edit the 'master logic' I don't have to do so in 30 jobs-

Comment: @user45867, most of time I use in-process exec. It shares the same process and log entry with the Parent package. Used Out-of-process when needed to separate executions - either because of memory limit on 32-bit execs, or due to other issues.
Yes, officially Child package returns no variables to the Parent, but the hacked way from above works. Alternative - in SSIS 2016+ you can use Control Flow templates which will be execcuted in Parent Package scope - added to the answer above.